# developer console: clear tests list

Tags: unit-test, developer-console

I need to test a bunch of test classes. The test runs are collecting in a huge list so i do not get an overview anymore. Is there any way to **clear** this list?

[image]

`Debug -> Clear` seems not to work with this view.

[image]

And under `Test` i can't find any useful option for that:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each test run is a single entry in that list and is an overview. If you click the '+' next to any entry in that list, you will see all of the tests for that individual run.

As far as clearing the list, that functionality does appear to be missing from the menus and doesn't even happen when logging out/back in.

Entries:
[image]

One Entry Open:
[image]

Comment: I agree completely, I recall looking all over for a way to clear this list, in the developer console and in the brower's Apex Test Execution. Option is missing.

Answer (score 6):

FYI - This is coming in Spring 14 - from Release Notes

> Clear Test and Code Coverage Results Refresh test and code coverage
>   results in the Developer Console by clicking Test > Clear Test Data.

Comment: That's good to know!

Comment: There's the fix!

Comment: Test -> Clear Test Data does not clear this list unfortunately. Not sure what it does exactly.

Comment: Still the same, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following query from Developer Console to query the current test class runs:

```
select id,ApexClass.Name,MethodName,FORMAT(TestTimestamp),Outcome,Message,RunTime
from ApexTestResult
where Outcome in ('Fail','Pass','CompileFail')
```

After executing query,  select the rows you want marked for deletion, and click Delete Row button.

Comment: I have tried the accepted answer on "Clear Test Data" in both Apex Test Results and Developer Console, it still left over some test results, I have to use above query and delete those rows manually. Thanks, Kevin!

Answer (score 3):

Menu:  Test /  Clear Test Data 
-- followed by F5 -- 
works for me! on Chrome in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned to clear the test data and code coverage results in the Developer Console click

1. Test -> Clear Test Data.
2. Refresh Developer Console window (e.g., with F5 on PC)

[image: Clear Test Data]
**Note**

*Also, it was mentioned correctly that following the steps above may not clear the data instantaneously, since it takes time for the CLEAR_TEST_RESULTS command to be executed by **ApexTestQueueServlet** on the backend site. It means a couple of refreshes could be required.*

It is possible to monitor this in Chrome Developer Console in a Network tab.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

***Test > Clear Test Data***

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tab_tests.htm&type=5

When you select this option, watch what happens in the Code Coverage pane.  This doesn't do what people want, though!

According to the product team, it has been delivered:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpiZAAQ

Grrrrrr.   Apparently, you have to wait a while for the results pane to be cleared.